# Set File attribute succed but retriving it fails

Tags: c++, windows, file-attributes

I use SetFileAttributesW to set custome file attribute e.g. 0x200008, and the SetFileAttributesW returns nonzero means that no error. but GetFileAttributesW retrieves file attribute ignoring the set attribute.

```
int main()
{
    uint32_t magic = 0x200008;
    DWORD attribute = GetFileAttributesW(L"test");
    cout << attribute << endl;
    if ((attribute & magic) == magic)
        cout << "has magic" << endl;
    else
    {
        attribute |= magic;
        cout << attribute << endl;
    }
    cout << SetFileAttributesW(L"test", attribute) << " " << GetLastError();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

and the output for each run
32
2097192
1 0

Any one can help me?

Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not any attributes valid, if you look in *wmd.h* you can find next definition:

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT < _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)

#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VALID_FLAGS          0x00007fb7
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VALID_SET_FLAGS      0x000031a7

#else

#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VALID_FLAGS          0x0002ffb7
#define FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VALID_SET_FLAGS      0x000231a7

#endif
```

so your custom file attribute 0x200008 not valid and will be undefined behavior. however in current implementation file systems ignore any values that they don't understand instead return error
See the [FASTFAT source](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/fileinfo.c#L2163):

```
    //
    //  Only permit the attributes that FAT understands.  The rest are silently
    //  dropped on the floor.
    //



    Attributes = (UCHAR)(Buffer->FileAttributes & (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY |
                                                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN |
                                                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM |
                                                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY |
                                                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE));
```

*NTFS* do the same.

so use only attributes which declared in windows header files and in mask *FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VALID_SET_FLAGS*

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use an value that is not supported. 0x200008 is not documented by Microsoft.

See for supported constants: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117(v=vs.85).aspx][1]